# Click to go to an anchored line

Tags: hyperref

It is possible to make a `hyperref` to go to page x, but how we can define a custom anchor to go a destination line?

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
  THE DESTINATION LINE (anchor x)
  \lipsum[3]
  \lipsum[4]
  CLICK HERE (go to anchor x)
  \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

How to click on `CLICK HERE` and goes to the `DESTINATION LINE`? I mean displaying `THE DESTINATION LINE` as the first line in the pdf reader.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use either `\hypertarget` + `\hyperlink` or `\phantomsection` with a `\label` and `\hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
  \phantomsection\label{here}THE DESTINATION LINE (anchor x)
  \lipsum[3]
  \lipsum[4]
  \hyperref[here]{CLICK HERE} (go to anchor x)
  \lipsum[5]

  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
  \hypertarget{here2}{}THE DESTINATION LINE (anchor x)
  \lipsum[3]
  \lipsum[4]
  \hyperlink{here2}{CLICK HERE} (go to anchor x)
  \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the `hyperlink` and `hypertarget` approach goes one line below the actual target position, as you can see by adding some text below with `\lipsum[1-5]`. This problem is also mentioned in these two questions: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212161/123129), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547719/123129).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `\hyperlink` and `hypertarget` from `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
  \lipsum[2]
  \hypertarget{mylink}{THE DESTINATION LINE (anchor x)}
  \lipsum[3]
  \lipsum[4]
  \hyperlink{mylink}{CLICK HERE (go to anchor x)}
  \lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```