# Hyperlink/Hypertarget Jumping to line below desired location

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, hyperlink, anchor, hypertarget

I have a custom commands for setting up two-way hyperlink/hypertargets:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Custom Commands
\newcommand{\pac}[2]{\hyperlink{{#1}1}{\hypertarget{{#1}0}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\jac}[1]{\hypertarget{{#1}1}{\hyperlink{{#1}0}{\ac{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{List of Acronyms}

% This table gives me fine control of acronym formatting
\begin{longtable}{ p{.20\textwidth}  p{.80\textwidth} } 
    \pac{frog}{FROG} & Finite Random Oscillator Response
\end{longtable}

% I made up this acronym
\acrodef{frog}[FROG]{Finite Random Oscillator Response}

% -----------------------------------------------------

\chapter{First chapter}
Get to know more about what is a \jac{frog}. 
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

But whenever the links appear in the final PDF it always jumps to the line below the target, requiring me to scroll up one line to view the hyperlink. I have spent a while trying to solve this, and I can't seem to find any working solution, I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212161/adjust-jump-location-of-hypertargets) - which is the exact issue I am having, but the solution with `\phantombreak` makes no difference, inserting a `\break` before partially fixes the issue in that it jumps to the right location, but now there is a huge line break whenever I want to use a hyperlink. Please advise as it is quite an irritating problem.

Edit: Added an example which reproduces the exact problem (verified in overleaf and in the downloaded PDF).

Comment: Make a complete example. That makes it *much* easier to test your issue.

Comment: You should look at the [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) code to see that the links are actually raised to properly show when the target is reached. Provide a minimal example that is complete (starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and replicates your problem) and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: just working on making a complete example to see if it can be replicated in an empty document. was hoping it would be a quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise the anchors:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pac}[2]{\hyperlink{{#1}1}{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{{#1}0}{}}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\jac}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{{#1}1}{}}{\hyperlink{{#1}0}{\ac{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: perfect thanks alot!

Comment: This seems to raise the links, rather than the position the link goes to for the anchor.

Comment: @jzadra yes, but it works ok, if you leave the second parameter empty: `\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myhypertarget}[1]{\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{#1}{}}}
\makeatother`